# Can't install updates nor plugins for Rhythmbox and other software

Tags: wireless, updates, plugins

I just installed Ubuntu 12.10 alongside Windows 7 and it seems a little lagged, running a bit slow. I attempt to check for uploads and plugins for Rhythmbox and Python, and it shows there are updates, but it gets stuck.

Also, the wireless icon shows that I'm connected to my wifi network, but I can't load any site.

I'm a beginner here, don't know if there's a way to fix this or if I should reinstall Ubuntu. In that case, is it possible to reinstall Ubuntu alongside Windows 7? How should I do it?

Comment: Ok, the 1st part can be caused by the 2nd part: a connection is needed to update software. Pointers: Can you connect to a website when wired? If so, do the updates work? If it does you only need to look at the problem of the wireless: re-check SSID, WPA password and other details in the wireless connection tab. Also have a look for any hardware lock. Can you add in details on your wireless card? Brand? There are some commands we can tell you that you can include in your answer to track the wireless down. To start please add in the result of `lspci -nn`.

Comment: If it is a Broadcomm this will tell you: `lspci | grep Broadcom` and also have a look here (it is technical though): http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-card-bcm43xx

Answer (score 1):

I could connect to facebook and google for a moment, now I can't anymore. That's why I asume it's a problem with Ubuntu. I'm using a usb wifi antenna, the brand is D-Link. Yesterday I downloaded the Chrome Installer, but today I attempted to install it and it asked for my password, started the install and finally failed.

The internet connection is fine, I have other PCs at home and they are working just fine, with a usb wifi antenna too.